# Eclipse will not recognize my Scala main

Tags: eclipse, scala

What I've tried:

1. Ensuring Scala perspective is set, disabled, set again
2. Ensuring that I right click on the Object that extends App

   - I never get 'Run as Scala application...' at this point
3. Defining an explicit 'main' in Object after removing 'extends App'

What I get is 'Run Configurations..." when I right-click on Object with main().  No matter what I do there, e.g. enter name of Object that extends App or has an explicit main, main() is never found and I get classloader stack trace dumps indicating that there is no main.

While I get no Scala compile errors, no matter what I try, I never get 'Run As...Scala Application'.

Code:

```
object fatfinger extends App {
  import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._ 
  import Common._ 
  import MongoFactory._ */
  object Insert { 
    def main(args: Array[String]) { 
      val apple = Stock("AAPL", 600)
      val google = Stock("GOOG", 650)
      val netflix = Stock("NFLX", 60) 
      saveStock(apple)
      saveStock(google)
      saveStock(netflix) }
    def saveStock(stock: Stock) {
      val mongoObj = buildMongoDbObject(stock)
      MongoFactory.collection.save(mongoObj) } } 
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Insert
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Insert
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Comment: Can you post the code including your main method?

Comment: Show us the code and the stack trace?

Comment: While this doesn't answer your question directly, I highly recommend using IntelliJ for Scala or Java development.

Comment: @DiaKharrat s/directly/in any sense of the word answer/  How about, "Instead of the fat finger, consider using the skinny one."

Comment: It's often because the definition of the main method isn't exactly right.  For instance, if it doesn't have `Unit` as the return type.

Comment: @DiaKharrat - Thanks for the helpful, professional answer.

Comment: import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._
import Common._
import MongoFactory._

 */

object Insert {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val apple = Stock("AAPL", 600)
    val google = Stock("GOOG", 650)
    val netflix = Stock("NFLX", 60)
  
    saveStock(apple)
    saveStock(google)
    saveStock(netflix)
  } 
  
  def saveStock(stock: Stock) {
    val mongoObj = buildMongoDbObject(stock)
    MongoFactory.collection.save(mongoObj)
  }
}

Comment: While I appreciate that the ":Unit" is missing, it did not work with "extends App" either.

Comment: Stack trace:  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Insert
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Insert
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)

Comment: Please edit your sample code into the question. There's a spurious close-comment "*/" in there too? Does a trivial hello-world app work?

Comment: I edited them back in. I do get a Run As Scala application, so I suspect something odd about your Eclipse install and not your exact code. Can you try that "hello world" app?

Comment: I did do the hello world and it worked as expected, so I am now integrating in other components to see if/when it breaks again.  Thanks!